# Encoding: knitr and child files

Tags: r, utf-8, knitr, pandoc

I am using Windows 7, R2.15.3 and RStudio 0.97.320 with knitr 1.1. Not sure what my `pandoc` version is, but I downloaded it a couple of days ago.

> sessionInfo()
>       R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01)
>       Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

```
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Argentina.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Argentina.1252    LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Argentina.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=Spanish_Argentina.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.15.3
```

I would like to get my reports both in `html` and Word, so I'm using markdown and pandoc.
I write in spanish with accents on vowels and tildes on the n: `á-ú` and `ñ`.

I have read many posts and I see problems similar to the one I'm having have been solved with new versions of `knitr`. But there is one issue I haven't found a solution for.

When I started, I used the `'system default'` encoding that appears in the `RStudio` dialog, i.e. `ISO 8859-1`, and the `RStudio` previews worked great. However when I tried to get Word documents, `pandoc` choked on the accentuated vowels. I found a post showing how to solve this using `iconv`:

> iconv -t utf-8 "myfile.md" | pandoc -o "myfile.docx"| iconv -f utf-8

While this did solve `pandoc's` unrecognized `utf-8` characters complaints, for some reason `pandoc` stops finding my plots, with an error like this one:

> pandoc: Could not find image `figure/Parent.png', skipping...

If I use only non-accent characters, pandoc finds the images with no problems. I looked at the two `.md` files with an `hex` editor, and I can't see any difference when I compare the sections that handle the figures:
`![plot of chunk Parent](figure/Parent.png)`
although obviously the accentuated characters are completely different... I have verified that the image files do exist in the figure folder

Anyway, after reading many posts I decided to set `RStudio` to use `UTF-8` encoding. With only one level of files things work great. For example, I can -independently- knit and then pandoc into Word the following 2 Rmd files:

````
Parent   -   SAVED WITH utf-8 encoding in RStudio
========================================================

u with an accent: "ú"  SAVED WITH utf-8 encoding in RStudio

```{r fig.width=7, fig.height=6}
plot(cars, main='Parent ú')
```
````

and separately:

````
Child   -   SAVED WITH utf-8 encoding in RStudio
========================================================

u with an accent: "ú"  Child file

```{r fig.width=7, fig.height=6}
plot(cars, main='One File Child ú')
```
````

and I get both 2 perfect prevues in `RStudio` and 2 perfect Word documents from `pandoc`.

The problem arises when I try to call the child part from the parent part. In other words, if I add to the first file the following lines:

````
```{r CallChild, child='TestUTFChild.Rmd'}

```
````

then all the accents in the child file become garbled as if the `UTF-8` was beeing interpreted as `ISO 8859-1`. `Pandoc` stops reading the file as well, complaining it's not `utf-8`.

If anybody could point me in the right direction, either:

**1.** With `pandoc` not finding the plots if I stay with `ISO 8859-1`. I have also tried `Windows-1252` because it's what I saw in the `sessionInfo`, but the result is the same.

**or**

**2.** With the call to the child file, if `UTF-8` is the way to go. I have looked for a way of setting some option to force the encoding in the child call, but I haven't found it yet.

Many thanks!

Comment: sounds like a bug in `knitr`; I'll look into it

Comment: @Yihui Thank you! I'm new to R, markdown and knitr, but I'm already amazed by the energy of the community and by your contribution to it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this problem should be fixed in the latest development version. See instructions in [the development repository](https://github.com/yihui/knitr#readme) on how to install the devel version. Then you should be able to choose UTF-8 in RStudio, and get a UTF-8 encoded output file.

Just in case anyone is interested in the gory details: the reason for the failure before was that I wrote the child output with the encoding you provided, but did not read it with the same encoding. Now I just avoid writing output files for [child documents](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/7d741e76dc6b3b58308c0bc6215091daf39cbae1).